# Cursor returns null

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the method below.

When i run it, the column "D" returns null values but if i  and run the printed sql string in sqllite manager, there are values though some rows are null.

Here is the method.

```
public List<ActiveTenancy> getUnInvoicedRooms(String mydate)
{
    List<ActiveTenancy> payments= new ArrayList<ActiveTenancy>();

        String sql ="SELECT Apartments.Number as N,Tenants.FirstName as F,Tenants.SurName as S ,"+
                   " (select Max(Rental_invoices.enddate)  from Rental_invoices inner Join Tenancy on Tenancy._id=Rental_invoices.tenancy_id "+
                  " where Tenancy.tenant_id=Tenants._id ) as D" +
                  " from Tenants "+               
                  " inner join Tenancy on Tenancy.tenant_id=Tenants._id "+
                 " inner join Apartments on Apartments._id=Tenancy.apartment_id "+
                " where Tenancy._id not  in(select  Rental_invoices.tenancy_id from Rental_invoices where enddate " + ">=?" + ")"+
                " and Tenancy.InActive=0";
 String[] args= new String[]{mydate};
        Log.e("sql", sql);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, args);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                ActiveTenancy a= new ActiveTenancy();
                a.setFirstName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("F")));
                a.setSurname(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("S")));
                a.setApartment(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("N")));

                if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("D"))!=null)
                {
                    Log.e("dddd",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("D")));
                try {
                    a.setEnd_date(fm.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("D"))));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                }
                payments .add(a);
            } while(c.moveToNext());
            }
         c.close();
    return payments;

}
```

Anything causing this?

Ronald

By not using the parameter holder "?" i.e passing the argument directly to the sql statement, it is now working.

```
String sql ="SELECT Apartments.Number as N,Tenants.FirstName as F,Tenants.SurName as S ,"+
                   " (select Max(Rental_invoices.enddate)  from Rental_invoices inner Join Tenancy on Tenancy._id=Rental_invoices.tenancy_id "+
                  " where Tenancy.tenant_id=Tenants._id ) as D" +
                  " from Tenants "+               
                  " inner join Tenancy on Tenancy.tenant_id=Tenants._id "+
                 " inner join Apartments on Apartments._id=Tenancy.apartment_id "+
                " where Tenancy._id not  in(select  Rental_invoices.tenancy_id from Rental_invoices where enddate " + ">='" + mydate + "'"+
                 ")"+
                " and Tenancy.InActive=0";
```

Any explanation ?....

Comment: You can't pass values as literals in raw query. For using literals you need to use Android standard query method of SQLiteDatabase.

Comment: But i can not use the android query method. It does not allow for sub queries which i am using.

Comment: @user2163887 The **?** placeholders are automatically converted to the proper type when you pass the parameters as a string array. And the strings become surrounded by **'**

Comment: Thank you for that information!..i was adding the character ('). That is why it was failing!